# Как правильно унаследовать параметры окна Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть такой вот класс:

```
class ADD(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,*args, *kwargs)
        self.title("Электронный читательский билет - Добавить нового читателя")
        self.geometry("900x450+300+200")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.configure(background='gray60')
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: sys.exit())
```

встретился с проблемой, что при создании дочернего класса и написании `super().__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)` выдаёт такую ошибку `AttributeError: 'SW2' object has no attribute 'tk'`. То есть надо унаследовать все данные окна и первого класса во второй, который открывается при нажатии кнопки(в самом коде она есть), но пишет такую ошибку. Помогите решить, пожалуйста

Comment: Я понял что нету у этого класса атрибута tk, но как бы можно было его добавить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При инициализации родительского класса через `super` не нужно передавать `self`. Он будет передан в `__init__` родительского класса автоматически, точно так же как при вызове метода от объекта. Т.е. по факту `super()` возвращает объект (а не просто родительский класс), у которого вы уже вызываете метод `__init__`.

Вот так будет работать:

```
super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Минимальный рабочий пример:

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys


class ADD(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Электронный читательский билет - Добавить нового читателя")
        self.geometry("900x450+300+200")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.configure(background='gray60')
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: sys.exit())


root =  tk.Tk()

tk.Button(text="Нажми меня", command=ADD).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное)